# Zxing.net.mobile, cannot get an event when scanner is closed xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm using the Zxing.net.mobile library in my xamarin.forms application, but I've found a big limitation in the using of it.
When the barcode scanner is active and I press the back button, the UI returns to the previous page but there's no way to execute code, because there's no way to trigger an event or passing a callback function to the scanner and the OnAppearing() method doesn't fire. Does anyone know a solution that might work? Thank you!

Edit: example code

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage


public MyPage()
{

    InitializeComponent();

}

public async void MyMethod()
{
    var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
    scanner.ScanContinuously(MyScanningAction);
}

private async void MyScanningAction(ZXing.Result scanningResult)
{

    ... do something ....
}
```

Comment: Do you return to previous screen without reading barcode? Or do you read barcode and then try to return to previous screen?

Comment: The method MyScanningAction is executed in loop. For going back you can only press the back button but neither the OnAppearing of the MyPage class nor the onBackButtonPressed are triggered